# using ngCookies angular for login

Tags: php, angularjs

I'm a beginner in angular. I want to use `ngCookie` for login. I'm using ajax get user information from a PHP backend, and if I have a user name, a logout button will be shown. Here is my code:

```
$http({
  method:'POST',
  url:'login.php',
  data:$.param(vm.formData),
  headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
}).then(Success);

function Success(response) {
  $cookies.get('username') = response.data.username;
  $cookies.put('username','username');
}
```

Here is my html

```
<div ng-show="username">
    <li><a href="">Hello {{username}}</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Log out</a></li>
</div>
```

**Error:**

> angular.js:12520 ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment

Comment: Did some reformatting and typo fixing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably the error

```
$cookies.get('username') = response.data.username;
```

**If you want to assign a value to username try this**

```
// Setting a cookie for the user
$cookies.put('currentUser', response.data.username);
// Retrieving a cookie for the user
var currentUser = $cookies.get('currentUser');
```

For a logout button you could try

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<button ng-if="user">Log Out</button>
</body>

angular.controller("MainCtrl",function($scope,$cookies){
$scope.user = $cookies.get("currentUser");
});
```

Comment: thank man . It work but logout button not display . How can i fix it

Comment: You will want to have it in your $scope for the ng-if ng-show etc